# Terraform Helm Chart Environment Variables

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, datadog

I am trying to set an environment variable for my Helm Chart deployment via terraform.  Currently my code looks like:

```
resource "helm_release" "datadog" {
  name       = "datadog"
  repository = "https://helm.datadoghq.com"
  chart      = "datadog"

  namespace        = "datadog"
  create_namespace = true

  # Default Configuration items
  set {
    name  = "datadog.apiKey"
    value = var.datadog_api_key
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.appKey"
    value = var.datadog_app_key
  }

  set {
    name  = "clusterAgent.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "targetSystem"
    value = "linux"
  }

  # Set Datadog Configuration Items

  # Event Collection
  set {
    name  = "agents.rbac.create"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.leaderElection"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.collectEvents"
    value = true
  }

  # Custom/External Metrics
  set {
    name  = "clusterAgent.metricsProvider.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  # APM Configuration
  set {
    name  = "datadog.apm.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  # Logs Configuration
  set {
    name  = "datadog.logs.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.logs.containerCollectAll"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.containerExcludeLogs"
    value = local.exclude_image_list
  }

  # Set logging verbosity, valid log levels are: trace, debug, info, warn, error, critical, off.  Default is info
  set {
    name  = "datadog.logLevel"
    value = "INFO"
  }

  # Process Collection Configuration
  set {
    name  = "datadog.processAgent.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  # Exclude Containers
  set {
    name  = "datadog.containerExclude"
    value = local.exclude_image_list
  }

  # Set Environment Variables
  # DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP is for DD AWS PrivateLink: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/guide/private-link/?tab=useast1
  set {
    name  = "env"
    value = "{DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP = true}"
  }
}
```

Notice at the bottom, how I am setting this.  I have tried passing this in as a string, which does not work.  I also have set this as a map which does not work either.  When I set it as a map, I get the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/datadog/helm.tf line 104, in resource "helm_release" "datadog":
│  104:     value = {"DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP" = true}
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "value": string required.
```

This is the helm chart that I am trying to modify:

https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/datadog

Comment: Helm chart expected type appears more like `["name"="DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP", "value"="true"]` according to the documentation, but unsure if that is completely correct.

Comment: When I tried that @MattSchuchard I got this:

range can't iterate over [{name=DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP

Comment: Terraform or Helm API error? I assume Helm because the types were converted.

Comment: Yes a helm error.  It doesn't like what was inputted and cannot iterate over that list properly

Comment: It could be sounds stupid, but you tried with  `value = {"DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP" = "true"}` ?

Comment: @DaniloCacace I actually have.  It throws an error saying that some of the yaml file cant iterate over an object formatted like that.  It doesn't like the values starting with just { and ending in }

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the value of [env](https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/datadog/values.yaml#L400) should be an array of objects with the keys (`name`, `value`), terraform allows you to define a key in an array element, so you can do that in two steps:

1. set the value for the key `name` for the first element
2. set the value for the key `value` for the first element

```
resource "helm_release" "datadog" {
  name       = "datadog"
  repository = "https://helm.datadoghq.com"
  chart      = "datadog"

  namespace        = "datadog"
  create_namespace = true

  # Default Configuration items
  set {
    name  = "datadog.apiKey"
    value = var.datadog_api_key
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.appKey"
    value = var.datadog_app_key
  }

  set {
    name  = "clusterAgent.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "targetSystem"
    value = "linux"
  }

  # Set Datadog Configuration Items

  # Event Collection
  set {
    name  = "agents.rbac.create"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.leaderElection"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.collectEvents"
    value = true
  }

  # Custom/External Metrics
  set {
    name  = "clusterAgent.metricsProvider.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  # APM Configuration
  set {
    name  = "datadog.apm.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  # Logs Configuration
  set {
    name  = "datadog.logs.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.logs.containerCollectAll"
    value = true
  }

  set {
    name  = "datadog.containerExcludeLogs"
    value = local.exclude_image_list
  }

  # Set logging verbosity, valid log levels are: trace, debug, info, warn, error, critical, off.  Default is info
  set {
    name  = "datadog.logLevel"
    value = "INFO"
  }

  # Process Collection Configuration
  set {
    name  = "datadog.processAgent.enabled"
    value = true
  }

  # Exclude Containers
  set {
    name  = "datadog.containerExclude"
    value = local.exclude_image_list
  }

  # Set Environment Variables
  # DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP is for DD AWS PrivateLink: https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/guide/private-link/?tab=useast1
  set {
    name  = "env[0].name"
    value = "DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP"
  }
  set {
    name  = "env[0].value"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me:

```
values = [<<YAML
datadog:
  env:
    - name: DD_LOGS_CONFIG_USE_HTTP
      value: "true"
YAML
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using [templatefile](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile):

```
resource "helm_release" "datadog_agent" {
  name       = "datadog-agent"
  chart      = "datadog"
  repository = "https://helm.datadoghq.com"
  version    = "3.7.3"
  namespace  = "default"
  set_sensitive {
    name  = "datadog.apiKey"
    value = var.datadog_api_key
  }
  set {
    name  = "datadog.site"
    value = "datadoghq.com"
  }
  values = [templatefile("${path.module}/templates/datadog_env_vars.tpl", {
    datadog_log_collection_only = var.datadog_log_collection_only ? "false" : "true"
  })]
```

The template:

```
datadog:
    env:
    - name: DD_CLOUD_PROVIDER_METADATA
      value: "aws"
    - name: DD_ENABLE_PAYLOADS_EVENTS
      value: "${datadog_log_collection_only}"
```

I only set env vars when there is no option to pass the value as an option for the `datadog-value.yaml` file in the helm/charts GitHub [repository](https://%20%20https://github.com/DataDog/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/datadog#all-configuration-options).